# Convert output from symbolic math (sym) to double

Tags: matlab, matrix, symbolic-math

I have a 2x2 matrix created with a symbol in matlab. Because of the symbol (x) all values are converted to integers such as

```
T14 =
   [ 1, - x - 8070491064644575/4503599627370496]
   [ 0,                                       1]
```

instead of

```
T14 =
   [ 1, - x - 1.7920]
   [ 0,                                       1]
```

The final matrix is created with

```
M = B16*T15*B15*T14*B14*T13*B13*T12*B12*T11*B11*T10
```

and contains mostly values like 
           `5098902830068945997216661558291421977734221147306628926962736786585701268374390522728433444885024747513/17917957937422433684459538244547554224973163977877196279199912807710334969441287563047019946172856926208`

I now want to convert all integer values to double values while keeping the symbol x. A simple `double` fails because `M` contains a symbol. How could I convert the whole matrix to a matlab like matrix with doubles?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you have a symbol without a set value I fear it is impossible, but since you ask I guess that you know what you are doing here.

It is possible to evaluate the expression before casting it:

```
syms x y;
y = subs(y,2); x=subs(x,[1,57/17;45/13,y*11]);
a = subs(x,'y',2);
b = double(a);
```

It is also possible to use `eval` on the expression before casting

```
syms x y;
y = subs(y,2); x=subs(x,[1,57/17;45/13,y*11]);
a = eval(x);
b = double(a);
```

Not sure if this is recommended or not but it works for this case.

Comment: It should be noted that the use of `eval` in the second case is effectively the same as calling [`vpa`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html), variable precision arithmetic. This means that `a` is still a `sym` class variable, but it  may have lost some precision depending on the value of `x` and the value of [`digits`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/digits.html). The precision should still be much greater than `double`, however.

Comment: Setting x to some value and getting the output matrix in double values is something I do with `MResult=eval(subs(M,xValue));`. That is however not the question. I want to have the symbolic result with double or at least float precision values.

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech I think that you need to explain it in more detail then. Try to use correct terms: use `sym` or symbol for symbols, integer for `int`, `float` or `double` for floating point values. You can for example never have symbols with double precision, because double precision mean that you want to do a cast from `sym` to `double`. The confusion increases since it, in your question says "A simple double fails because M contains a symbol". This somehow implies that you try to do a cast to `double`, but fails since you have `M` in the matrix. I provided a solution to get rid of `M`.

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech I would also like to add that if the problem is that you want fewer digits printed you should state this in your problem formulation